# How to host multiple sites with different domains on a single IP address?

Tags: nginx, networking, server, dns, hosting

I want to host multiple sites with different domains on a single IP address. Shopify for example says you need to set the A record of your domain to `23.227.38.65` . This IP address is the same for all Shopify stores. When I goto the IP address directly I get Cloudflare Error 1003: Direct IP access not allowed. How do companies host multiple sites with different domains onto a single IP address with Nginx for example?

And how does Shopify distinguish the request with a direct request and a request from my store? Only the domain name?

Comment: The concept is called [Virtual Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting). Basically, whatever you typed in browser address bar (either hostname or IP address) is sent to the server (in http `Host` header) so it can distinguish which site exactly you need)

Comment: Configuring virtual hosts on an Nginx server is covered in [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).